Is ישמעאל Yishm'a-EL Shimon שמעון?
Famously in this week's parshah וְזֹ֣את הַבְּרָכָ֗ה V'zot haBrakah Moses our master gives his last will and testament, his ברכה berakah, benediction to each of the 12 Tribes of Israel
But as many readers have pointed out, and commentators have addressed: not all 12 of the tribes appear to be listed.
The Tribe of Simeon, שמעון Shimon, appears to be missing.
Elsewhere commentators have wrestled with this issue, variously.
Rashi says that:

לְשִׁמְעוֹן מִתּוֹךְ בִּרְכוֹתָיו שֶׁל יְהוּדָה
"Shimon's blessing is within Yehudah's"


שְׁמַ֤ע יְהֹוָה֙ ק֣וֹל יְהוּדָ֔ה וְאֶל־עַמּ֖וֹ תְּבִיאֶ֑נּוּ יָדָיו֙ רָ֣ב ל֔וֹ וְעֵ֥זֶר מִצָּרָ֖יו תִּהְיֶֽה׃
Shema'Ya (שמע יהוה), the voice of Judah: restore him to his people, through his own hands strive for him. Help him against his foes.

Remarkably Rashi says that Shema'Ya (שמע יהוה) is Shimon's name! Tying back to the story of his birth to our foremother Leah:

וַתַּ֣הַר עוֹד֮ וַתֵּ֣לֶד בֵּן֒ וַתֹּ֗אמֶר כִּֽי־שָׁמַ֤ע יְהֹוָה֙ כִּֽי־שְׂנוּאָ֣ה אָנֹ֔כִי וַיִּתֶּן־לִ֖י גַּם־אֶת־זֶ֑ה וַתִּקְרָ֥א שְׁמ֖וֹ שִׁמְעֽוֹן׃
And she conceived again and bore a son, and declared, “This is because יהוה heard that I was unloved so he has given me this one also”; so she named him Shimon: G!d heard.

Besides the obvious connection between the names Yishma'EL-Shema'Ya-Shimon (God will hear, G!d hears, G!d has heard) and the interesteing coincidence that Yishma'El also has 12 tribes .... the biographers have tried to establish this connection between Shimon & Yishma'El
Indeed as the Jewish Encylopedia records: "Many attempts have been made to connect Simeon with Ishmael and Massa, and with the founders of Mecca" 1 but it cites no source.
So: is there more to this story and is Yishma'El Shimon and is Shimon Yishma'El?

That quotes links to the Jewish Encyclopedia, not the JVL

The JE actually does cite its sources, it just puts them on the bottom without footnotes as is customary by many encyclopedias. This entry is no different. Have you considered going through the sources cited there?

Yes: it does provide a bibliography, but it doesn't provide a citation for this particular point ... which is strange since it almost seems to require time travel.

Just a hunch: maybe this explains the excellent relations between Yishma'EL and Yehudah ... besides the renowned commitment to Monotheism of both.

I'm going on a limb here, but I'm guessing you haven't opened up a physical copy of the Jewish Encyclopedia. So when you say that there isn't a citation for this, you aren't contradicting anything that I wrote in my previous comment. So, my question stands: Why haven't you considered going through the sources in the bibliography?
